# Creating a dataframe of Shapely polygons gives "ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples"

Tags: python, polygon, valueerror, shapely

I want to create a heatmap of say, provincial population of China and I found [this guide](http://sensitivecities.com/so-youd-like-to-make-a-map-using-python-EN.html#.Ut3k7bS-thF) to a similar problem here.

I have no problem going through the example code though I have to admit that I don't thoroughly understand them all. However when I was trying to mimic the example by using the shapefile of China, the code ran ok till the following

```
df_map = pd.DataFrame({
    'poly': [Polygon(xy) for xy in m.china],
    'ward_name': [ward['NAME'] for ward in m.china_info]})
```

It generates an error that says

```
ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples
```

Can someone please explain to me what causes this error?

Answer (score 5):

It is usually a good idea to include the complete error message in your question when you report an error.  Python tracebacks include more information than the final error message, including the module and line number where the error occurred.

Your error is occurring in the `shapely` code.  I can reproduce the error message by passing `Polygon` a sequence of just two points; `Polygon` requires at least three points.  Here's an example.

Import `Polygon` from the shapely library:

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Polygon
```

Passing a sequence of three points works:

```
>>> p = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)])
```

But giving just two points causes the error:

```
>>> p = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/warren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 229, in __init__
    self._geom, self._ndim = geos_polygon_from_py(shell, holes)
  File "/home/warren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 445, in geos_polygon_from_py
    geos_shell, ndim = geos_linearring_from_py(shell)
  File "/home/warren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 393, in geos_linearring_from_py
    "A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples")
ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples
```

Apparently there is an item in `m.china` that has fewer than three points.  You are using ipython, so you could print `m.china` before attempting to create `df_map`.  That should help you determine what is going on.

Comment: Thank you Warren. You are right. I checked m.china list. It has a few elements each of which has fewer than three points. But what can I do now? m.china, just like m.london, is directly read from the shapefiles.