# Looping through a dataframe of polygons gives "ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples"

Tags: python, dataframe, valueerror, shapely

I have a dataframe of the neighborhoods of Chicago with their respective polygons

```
    Neighborhood    Polygons    Polygons_tup
0   Grand Boulevard [[[-87.60670812560363, 41.81681377137387], [-8...   [(-87.60670812560363, 41.81681377137387), (-87...
1   Printers Row    [[[-87.62760697485339, 41.87437097785366], [-8...   [(-87.62760697485339, 41.87437097785366), (-87...
2   United Center   [[[-87.66706868914592, 41.88885187769542], [-8...   [(-87.66706868914592, 41.88885187769542), (-87...
3   Sheffield & DePaul  [[[-87.65833494805524, 41.921661442291786], [-...   [(-87.65833494805524, 41.921661442291786), (-8...
4   Humboldt Park   [[[-87.74059567509258, 41.88782316893226], [-8...   [(-87.74059567509258, 41.88782316893226), (-87...
```

What I am trying to do is for any given latitude, longitude point, I want to loop through all of the polygons and see if the point is within one of these neighborhoods.

I tried using a for loop to loop through the data frame

```
def neighbor_finder(long,lat):
    for index,row in df_new.iterrows():
        poly = row['Polygons_tup']
        polygon = Polygon(poly)
        point = Point(lat, long)
        if polygon.contains(point):
            neighborhood = row['Neighborhood']
            print(neighborhood)
```

I was expecting the name of the neighborhood to be printed out but when I ran

```
long = -87.723960
lat = 41.825320
neighbor_finder(long, lat)
```

Instead, I received an error

```
A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples
```

Is there something wrong with my for loop?

Comment: I think the error is pretty self-explanatory. Some lists in `Polygons_tup` have less than 3 coordinate tuples, and you can't construct a polygon with <3 points. Add if-condition before constructing a polygon to see which rows the error comes from.

Comment: @Georgy, that actually worked! I did not look at the simplest solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a dataframe of Shapely polygons gives "ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248587/creating-a-dataframe-of-shapely-polygons-gives-valueerror-a-linearring-must-ha)